# Finding the 95% confidence interval using the confint function in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I'm analysing the `Boston` dataset from the [MASS package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf) in R. I begin by carrying out a linear regression with `medv` as the response and `ptratio` as the only predictor:

```
lm.Boston <- lm(formula = medv ~ ptratio, data = Boston.df)
```

I then want to find a 95% confidence interval for the estimate of `ptratio`. My understanding is that I can do this using the [`confint` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/confint):

```
confint(lm.Boston, level = 0.95)

                2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 56.393267 68.295988
ptratio     -2.477454 -1.836897
```

But notice that, despite the fact that I have explicitly specified `level = 0.95`, the output gives 2.5% and 97.5%.

Furthermore, when I attempt to explicitly pass the variable as a parameter, I get the following error:

```
confint(lm.Boston, parm = ptratio, level = 0.95)

Error in confint.lm(lm.Boston, parm = ptratio, level = 0.95) : object 'ptratio' not found
```

So what's wrong in these two cases?

---

### EDIT

```
confint(lm.Boston, parm = 'ptratio', level = 0.95)
```

works:

```
            2.5 %    97.5 %
ptratio -2.477454 -1.836897
```

Comment: A 95% confidence interval falls between the 2.5% and 97.5% centiles of a distribution. Remember, 97.5 - 2.5 = 95, so if you want to know where 95% of observations lie around the centre of a distribution,  you need to choose the central 95%, which is between 2.5% and 97.5%. Similarly, a parameter's confidence interval is the middle 95% of the area under the parameter's likelihood function. For example, you would report the the estimated Coefficient for `ptratio` as "ptratio = -2.157, (95% confidence interval -2.477454 to -1.836897)"